# Laravel: How to redirect form data?

Tags: php, redirect, authentication, laravel-5.4

I'm trying to do redirect unsuccessful login with form data.

my code:

```
//if unsuccessful, redirect back to login with form data
return redirect()
    ->back()
    ->withInput($request->only('email', 'password','remember'));
```

However this returns with only email data, how can I return password data?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, it very bad form to bring back passwords.

As for the question, you can try using Laravel's `old()` function. This shows previously entered input data after for example a submission goes wrong.

Example input field:

```
<input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" required value="{{ old('email') }}">
```

More info : https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/requests#old-input

Comment: Elaborate more on why it's bad to help the OP to understand more

Comment: Also this is not my form, i think i don't write clear enough sorry for this. This is a part of login controller function. So it will just do the redirect. But I don't understand why password data is not returning? I don't return pw in the system but i'm trying to understand why.